# Spring (3.1.0 Release) @Value: Auto wiring exception reading from config xml

Tags: spring, autowired

Code has following reference to a configuration file in classpath.

```
....
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Repository
public class TestTaxes implements TaxIntface {

@Autowired
protected ContxtManager contxtManager;
@Autowired
protected TxEngLoader txEng;
@Value("#{paths}")
List<String> paths;
....
```

config.xml has following entry

```
....
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<beans xsi:schemaLocation=" http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans">
<util:properties location="classpath:/eng.properties" id="engProperties"/>
<util:list id="paths" value-type="java.lang.String">
  <value>Calc.drl</value>
  <value>GetTx.drl</value>
</util:list>
</beans>
```

While deploying application I am getting spring auto wiring exception:

```
Error creating bean with name 'testTaxes': Injection of autowired dependencies failed;
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: java.util.List com.x.y.z.TestTaxes.paths;
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed;
nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:(pos 0): Field or property 'paths' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext'
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Why aren't you simply using `@Autowired` with a `@Qualifier` or `@Resource` with a bean name?

Comment: @Value("#{paths}")... part is in another product code which I can not change. I am extending TestTaxes class in my code and that's where it fails when tries to initialize the parent class...

Comment: I tried using 
    @Scope(value = "step", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS) 
to the subclass that I created which worked but then it gets stuck on the parent class TestTaxes...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already found the solution for this problem myself.
All the setting and configuration was correct; but @ImportResource had the entry missing which was config.xml and it had list of values for paths.

Answer (score 0):

This is because a Properties is a map and not a list.
If you want to take a string from a list of properties files need to do something like:

**paths.properties**

```
value.list.properties=string1,string2,string3
```

In the java class you need to do the following thing:

```
public class TestTaxes implements TaxIntface {

@Value("#{paths['value.list.properties']}")
List<String> paths;
```